# How to modify or delete the maxWidth of a column?

Tags: ag-grid

eg:

```js
const colDefs =   [{ field: 'country', maxWidth:100,}]
```

when the grid ready,i use the `setColumnDefs` to change maxWidth, but it didn't take effect.

```js
function changeMaxWidth(){
  const colDefs = gridOptions.api.getColumnDefs()
  colDefs[0].maxWidth = 130 
  gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(colDefs)
}
```

this is example: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6iUd4R4XMLExU3s9)

Comment: Add my needs： I just want to not exceed a maximum width when using `api.autoSizeAllColumns()`, other times such as dragging and dropping the column width can exceed the limit.

Answer (score 1):

MaxWidth can not be changed that way via the `setColumnDefs`.
from the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/value-getters/#expiring-the-value-cache), only the framework bound attributes would change using the `setColumnDefs`, which probably means the headerframework or `cellRendererFramework` as those would return reactJs or angular components.

The only attribute related to the maxWidth that you can change dynamically is `width` which will set the current width.([docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/react/column-updating-definitions/#changing-column-state))

You can also use `api.sizeColumnsToFit()` to try and fit the available table width, or `api.autoSizeAllColumns()` to size the columns based on their content (both these methods would take consideration of `width`, `maxWidth`, and `minWidth`).

Comment: In the [doc](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/column-updating-definitions/#updating-column-definitions), 
i saw "All properties of a column definition can be updated.", doesn't seem to be the case.
Excuse me what you said "only the framework bound attributes would change using the setColumnDefs", I didn't find it in the document...

Comment: in the second docs, i mentioned, it is said so.

Comment: Thx,Although the document does not say clearly, it may be that the properties related to react will take effect. Otherwise, it is impossible to explain why the maxWidth does not take effect, because similar stateless properties such as headerName will also take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are like me just want to not exceed the maxWidth when using `api.autoSizeAllColumns()`, other times (for example, drag and drop column width) may exceed the limit, you can refer to my approach.

```css
.ag-center-cols-container > span:last-child{
  max-width: 248px;
}
```

This style will limit the size of the adaptive width when `api.autoSizeAllColumns()`

Answer (score 0):

Might not be interesting but also look into column "flex" as it solves a lot of autosizing-issues that people have: https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation/javascript/column-sizing/

Comment: Yeah,i konw this, column "flex"  often required that one or more columns fill the entire available space in the grid,but now what I want is that all column widths adapt to the content